# Why do some applications ship with shared libraries?

Tags: linux, .so

I was looking through `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and noticed that some applications, such as gedit, ship with shared object files. I understand why libraries ship with shared libs, but what advantage is there for a stand-alone application to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone want to write plugins for these application they can use a provided API which is usable by the shared libraries.

Also when you have multiple executables using the library in one software-package you can reduce the size of those binaries by shipping also a shared library instead of linking it staticly into each binary.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the gedit example, it comes with following shared libraries:

```
/usr/lib64/gedit/libgedit.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libdocinfo.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libfilebrowser.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libmodelines.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libsort.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libspell.so
/usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/libtime.so
```

The first one, `libgedit.so`, is for other applications that can reuse the editor component of gedit.

The rest of them are plugins for gedit. While they are built and distributed together with the application, they are independent addons and gedit should work without them too. 3rd party plugins could be there as well.